# Akka FSM in Java

Tags: java, akka

Following the [Akka FSM documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fsm.html) Im implementing the given sample. First of all I get that the state machine is running in a initialisation block. But how does one pass any variables/configuration using Props ? I cannot find any documentation or examples around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization block is just convenience to run something on construction so you can implement the whole init logic in a "normal" constructor taking parameters.